# Mule avoiding warning of missing variable

Tags: xpath, mule

I have a flow that looks inside the incoming XML payload and tries to set the value of an optional element to a variable.

```
<set-session-variable variableName="priority"
        value="#[xpath:/S:Envelope/S:Header/eai:priority]"/>
```

The behavior is fine.  However, if the priority element is not present, a message is written out to the log.

```
Variable with key {0}, not found on message using {1}. Since the value was marked optional, nothing was set on the message for this variable
```

The support team gets worried when they see messages like this.

Is there some expression that can be used instead of the one I have that will avoid the message when the priority element is not present?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to what you are asking is to first check the value of the xpath expression before assigning to variable. Assign to variable only if value if present.

Comment: Well, yes, I understand.  My question is whether there is an expression that allows it to be done to avoid complicating the flow with choices, whens and otherwises.

Comment: yeah I am not sure if Mule provides that configurability without modifying core classes